# Serverfault and Unix/Linux

Tags: discussion

Is there a general rule when to ask a question on the "Unix and Linux" StackExchange rather than on "serverfault"?

Or: When should questions in one of these two be migrated to the other one?

Comment: Hmm. We probably need to ask U&L which questions they do/don't want. In the past I've only sent them hardcore U&L questions, like modifying kernel, etc, that don't really relate to sysadmining

Comment: @MarkHenderson We have some flaggers who really want general Linux questions (even ones very commonly done by sysadmins) going that direction, so yeah. Some cross-talk is probably needed here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<sub>(Note: I'm a [UL mod](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/73/michael-mrozek), so when I say "we" I mean Unix and Linux Stack Exchange)</sub>

If it's a question about Unix and Linux and you don't want it, odds are we do; we're [fairly inclusive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). We have this same overlap problem with other sites, notably Ask Ubuntu, so here's what we do with them:

- Questions about Ubuntu that have no bearing on other distros are migrated from UL to AU
- Questions about Unix or Linux that don't apply to Ubuntu at all are migrated from AU to UL
- All other questions are left where they're posted unless the OP asks us to move them

I generally apply the same logic to other sites, even if we haven't specifically talked about it. So we almost never migrate here (3 times in the last 3 months), because it's rare for someone to ask a sysadmin question that doesn't involve Unix or Linux. Similarly, we don't expect you to migrate Unix/Linux questions to us if they're on-topic here -- you should only migrate a question if SF isn't a good place for it, or the OP changes their mind and wants it somewhere else.

I'll also mention that one thing you shouldn't do (or encourage others to do) is [cross-post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting). Sites differ on their tolerance for cross-posting; we usually close a question if we find out it was posted on multiple sites. Either pick a site, or tailor your question for the individual sites you're asking it on -- don't just copy/paste it to all the sites that sound relevant

Comment: What about Debian questions?

Comment: @Andrew Sure; all Linux distros are fine

Comment: Migrating an unanswered question is not crossposting, I assume?

Comment: @Nils Migrating a question is fine, what matters is that the question is not open on more than one site. This goes even if the question has answers, but unless we have a good feel for the target community, we (SE mods in general) only migrate questions with the explicit agreement of a moderator or user in good standing on the receiving site.

Comment: I came here because I had the question the OP had; about the specific scope of UL and SF, but then this response dives into AU which is completely outside the scope, because I still don't feel like I know the answer to the original question.

Answer (score 11):

There's inevitable overlap between U&L and SF. Generally, on the U&L side, we only migrate a question if it's definitely off-topic or if the asker agrees.

U&L generally isn't very strong on dedicated-server applications. For example only .6% of U&L's questions are about [apache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache), contrasted with SF's >8%. U&L doesn't cater much for systems that people administrate through front-ends such as CPanel, usually we assume that a command line is available. Another kind of questions that will fare better on SF is practical performance questions (like [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/305595/maximizing-throughput-of-virtual-file-systems) which was migrated from U&L to SF).

A large class of questions that can be migrated to U&L is shell scripting questions. Some of these feel generic on SF, because the techniques involved aren't specific to system administration. The same goes for package management questions. As far as I remember, SF has a good track record for migrations to U&L, so if you keep doing more of the same, that's fine.

The main thing to keep in mind about U&L is that programming questions are off-topic. If someone posts a unix programming question on SF, migrate it to SO.

Comment: I think the main difference between UL and SF is that SF has a bigger audience - and has the broader topic.

Comment: @Nils No, that's not it. UL gets more SU-type questions than SF-type questions. SU and SF care who you are (amateur/pro computer user), U&L cares what you do (use unix, whatever for). It's a horizontal/vertical division.

Answer (score 4):

The community consensus seems to be that if it is clearly for production servers you are working on, it stays. If it is a general Linux question, such as advanced `find` wizardry, regardless of production-machine status it generally goes to U&L (or gets some flags to that effect).

Linux *software*, on the other hand, is another story entirely and generally is answered on a topic-by-topic basis.

Now, some questions can have a happy life on both sites since we have strong Linux users who answer questions both here and there. It is *my opinion* that such overlap is healthy, and not everything needs to be ruthlessly migrated to the other site.

Answer (score -9):

U&L and SF should just be SF. Totally crazy splitting off some Qs to U&L.

Just creates confusion and makes SF less valuable to me as a sysop.

Comment: They have different scopes, you might as well advocate combining [French.SE] and [German.SE] because they're both Language sites.

Comment: On UL you can keep track. SF has just too many questions per day, so I would rather vote for creating a Windows-Server branch to diversify SF further.

Comment: @ChrisS French and German don't have the same level of overlap as 'Production servers' and 'Linux and Unix'.

Comment: @mikemaccana You should probably go read [SF]'s scope before making any more comments that sound ignorant.